# Maximize Google chrome every 10 mins Automate

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cmd.exe, automation, windows-task-scheduler

Due to the nature of my job , I need to check chrome browser every 10 mins after that I minimize my browser and do entry work. Normally I'm using timers or alerts but is it possible automatically existing chrome browser which minimized to taskbar maximizes itself even though I'm working on different application like excel.

I used Tinytask created a macro and task scheduled it. It works some times other times not. Looking for native windows resolution.

Kindly help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save this as a script like `MyScript.ps1` and run it with powershell:

```sh
# maximizes chrome every 10 minutes
Add-Type -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32 -MemberDefinition '
  [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'

While ($true) {
  Write-Host 'Waiting for 10 minutes'
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 600

  # Find most recent chrome window
  $Window = (Get-Process chrome | Where MainWindowHandle -NE 0)[0].MainWindowHandle

  # Maximize window and activate
  [Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($Window,3) | Out-Null

  Write-Host "Maximized chrome window $window"
}

# other ShowWindow values like Minimize (2) here: 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow
```

This will maximize your chrome window every 10 minutes until you close the powershell window. If you open a second chrome window, it should pick the newest one

Comment: I really love powershell scripts. Thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is not a native Windows app, but effective: use Nirstoft's small [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) app to activate the app window, calling it either with Task Manager, or in an .bat file with an infinite loop, pausing 600 seconds.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\NirSoft\NirCmd\nircmd" win activate process <process.exe>`

For example, I wanted to make Firefox single-instance, so start it with this script:

```
@echo off
tasklist | findstr "firefox.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto running
if %errorlevel% equ 1 start " " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
exit

:running
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NirSoft\NirCmd\nircmd" win activate process firefox.exe 
exit
```

If Firefox is not running, it starts it; if already running, it's brought to front with *win activate process*.